# How to split a string vector and recompose it in the original form

Tags: string, r, split

I would like to split a string vector, process its tokens, and then recompose it in the original form.

Please consider the following

```
vector.in <- c("red rum", "mur der", "red rum", "mur der")
length(vector.in)
# [1] 4
vector.splt <- strsplit(vector.in, "\\s")
vector.splt <- unlist(vector.splt)
vector.out <- paste(vector.splt, sep="", collapse=" ")
```

and of course

```
length(vector.out)
# [1] 1
```

How should I process it so to output a vector with the same form and length as the original `vector.in`, that is without loosing any information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unlist` is the problem.  That removes the structure too early.  Then you need to loop around the elements and pass to the `paste` function.  I will use `lapply` for the loop:

```
vector.in <- c("red rum", "mur der", "red rum", "mur der")
vector.splt <- strsplit(vector.in, "\\s")
unlist(lapply(vector.splt, paste, collapse=' '))
## [1] "red rum" "mur der" "red rum" "mur der"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `gsubfn` function in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) does that.  For example, here we split the input into words, apply a function (represented in formula notation) to each word where in this case the function parenthesizes each word and then we put it all back together:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> gsubfn("\\w+", ~ sprintf("(%s)", x), vector.in)
[1] "(red) (rum)" "(mur) (der)" "(red) (rum)" "(mur) (der)"
```